# Question on continuity with [x]

Tags: limits, continuity

given the function $f(x)=\frac{2[x]}{3x-[x]}$
the question is to find continuity of the function at $x=1$ and $x=\frac{-1}{2}$
note: [x] denotes the largest integer which is less than or equal to x.

what i did is,

at $x=1$,
 $$\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}f(1+h)=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{2[1+h]}{3(1+h)-[1+h]}$$ 
 i think $ [1+h]=1$ and
         $[1-h]=0$ through the definition of [x].
$$\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}f(1+h)=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{2[1+h]}{3(1+h)-[1+h]}=\frac{2*1}{3-1}=1$$
similarly 
 $$\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}f(1-h)=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{2[1-h]}{3(1-h)-[1-h]}=0$$

here $$\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}f(1+h)\not\equiv \lim_{h\rightarrow 0}f(1-h)$$

there fore it is discontinuous at x=1.
In the same way it is continuous at x=1/2.

Is this process correct??

Comment: Yes correct.${}$

Comment: But in my book the answer given is continuous at x=1 and discontinuous at x=-0.5

Comment: It is continuous at $1$ from the right.

Comment: If that is what your book really says, then it's wrong.

Comment: Note that $[x]$ usually denotes the nearest integer.

Answer (score 0):

It is continuous at $1$ from the right since

> $$\lim_{h\to 0} f(1+h) = f(1),\quad h>0.$$

Comment: what do you mean by "from the right"?

Comment: @srishti: Do you the notion of right and left limits? The right limit means you approach the point $x=1$ from the right; i.e with values bigger than $1$, so that's why I wrote $\lim_{h\to 0} f(1+h), \quad h>0 $.

Comment: @srishti: In your case the right limit of the function at $x=1$ equals the value of the function at the point $x=1$ which is $f(1)$.

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal if you're working in a space with values to the left of $1$ then shouldn't you require first that $\lim_{h \to 0} f(1+h)$ exists, and then compare it to the value at $x=1$? In other words here the limit doesn't actually exist (since I'm assuming the domain of choice is $\mathbb{R}$) thus we cannot ask does the limit equal the value at the point.

Comment: What's the downvote for?